# Python regular expression matching using $

Tags: python

I'm using Python 2.7.0 and and doing the following in the interpreter:

```
>>> re.search (r"//\s*.*?$", "//\n\na12345678", flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL).group()
'//\n\na12345678'
```

This is not what I expected.  I though $ would match before the endline, but it included the two endline characters AND text after that?

Surprisingly, this works:

```
>>> re.search (r"//\s*.*?$", "//1\n\na12345678", flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL).group()
'//1'
```

What am I misunderstanding here about python regular expressions?

Some more info:

```
>>> re.search(r"//\s*.*", "//\n  test").group()
'//\n  test'
>>> re.search(r"//\s*.*", "//1\n  test").group()
'//1'
```

This last block of code is without MUTLILINE and DOTALL?  What am I misunderstanding here?  .* shouldn't be matching the newline, and definitely not go past it, right?

Comment: *This is without MUTLILINE and DOTALL?* - not according to your code...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\s` can match newlines, and when you use the `re.DOTALL` flag `.` can also match newlines.

In the first case your `\s*` is greedy, so since the first characters after the `//` in your string are newlines they will be matched by the `\s*`, and then the `.*?` will match the final line so that the `$` can match at the very end of the string.

In the second case the `\s*` cannot match because of the `1` after the `//`, and the `.*?` will only match up to just before the first newline since it is lazy.

If you want to match all whitespace except for newlines, you can use `[ \t]` in place of `\s`.  It actually looks like for your examples you will get the expected behavior if you just use the regex `//.*?$` with the `re.MULTILINE` flag enabled (`re.DOTALL` can be included as well, it will not make a difference in this case).

Comment: Thank-you!  I didn't even think about the first \s*!